# System.io.Directory.GetFiles with more that one file type

Tags: .net

How do I do `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.tif")`  and `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.jpg")` in the same call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way I believe (scanning the directory only once, and yielding results without first building up the whole list) is like this:

```
var extensions = new[] {".jpg", ".tif"};
var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
            where extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f))
            select f;
```

Of course, if you need to loop over the results more than once it's probably best to store the result in a list anyway.

Comment: A much more elegant and readable solution! I like it best. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter by yourself and you want to spare the OS to traverse the directory nodes again then you can do

```
        string[] extensionFilters = new string[] { ".jpg", ".tif" };

        string[] filtered = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.*")
                            .Where(filename => extensionFilters.Any(x => 
                                   filename.EndsWith(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sourceFolder = "C:\\";
var filters = "*.tif|*.jpg";
var files = filters.Split('|').SelectMany(filter => System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter)).ToArray();
```

where sourceFolder is the path to the folder you wish to select files from.